# Translated text in API response

Tags: magento2, rest-api, postman

Is it possible to get translated text in API response while testing the API in postman? I have already added required `csv` `i18n` folder in the path: `app/code folder`.

I am passing store code into the url like this in my custom api call: `/rest/ar_sa/V1/contact`

I am getting message in english only. I need to get that message in Arabic while `ar_sa` is pass into url.

Does any one have solution of this ?

Comment: the rest of the store-view is in the correct language?

Comment: @PhilippSander All store views are in the correct language. I am having two different site with two stores in each. One is english store view and second is arabic.

Comment: where did you place the csv file exactly (like full path from magento root including the filename itself)?

Comment: @DavidVerholen Here is the full path : webroot/magento2/app/i18n/mageplaza/ar_sa/ar_SA.csv

Answer (score -2):

Put the `ar_SA.csv` file here:

> webroot/magento2/app/code/Mageplaza/ModuleName/i18n/ar_SA.csv

Clear cache:

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```